# Five images on the same row with responsive background (responsive row)

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I tried to create a responsive row that contain five inline images on desktop, two columns on the tablet and on column on smartphone.

I also put a background image below this five images, but I would like this images will be responsive when I use a small desktop, a table or a smartphone.

This is what I tried to do but I don't think it is a good solution because the background is not really responsive:

HTML

```
<div class="background">
 <div class="layer">
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SILVIA-FAIT-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CLAUDIO-ZAMPARELLI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ROBERTA-MAGNANI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BARBARA-VANNI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SANDRO-CAMPANI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
 </dvi>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
    background-image: url('http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 100px 300px 100px;
}

.div-diviso {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
 .layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 900px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 1500px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

This is what I want:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8WW6.jpg)

Comment: You could probably make this fairly responsive without breakpoints by setting all the `.div-diviso` elements to `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: If you want to use an external library [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) makes exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.background {
    background-image: url('http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.div-diviso {
    width: 17%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.div-diviso img {
  width: 100%;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
 .layer {
    padding: 0px 0px 900px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 47%;
    padding: 10px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .layer {
    padding: 0px 0px 1500px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 5px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <div class="layer">
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SILVIA-FAIT-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CLAUDIO-ZAMPARELLI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ROBERTA-MAGNANI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BARBARA-VANNI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SANDRO-CAMPANI-2017_980.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Chage the width percentage and use display: inline-block instead of position.
NOTE: You do not have to repeat the same code in media query